# How do I fix an unhandled exception in my dll?

Tags: c++, memory

Im writing an aimbot for a game called assault cube and I have written a function to grab all of the players in the game. Im currently trying to get the team of the player that my function gets, but for some weird reason I get an error.
The Error: Unhandled exception at 0x08ED66D0 (finalaimbot.dll) in ac_client.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000003CA.

This is really weird because the address im reading from is way higher than 0x3CA.

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

DWORD EntityList = 0x50F4F8;
DWORD Player = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x50F4F4);
DWORD OnlinePlayers = 0x50F500;

DWORD MouseX = 0x40;
DWORD MouseY = 0x44;

DWORD HeadX = 0x4;
DWORD HeadY = 0x8;
DWORD HeadZ = 0xC;

DWORD Team = 0x3C2;

using namespace std;

struct vec3 {
    float x, y, z;
};
float GetDistance3D(vec3 m_pos, vec3 en_pos)
{
    float res = (float)(sqrt(((en_pos.x - m_pos.x) * (en_pos.x - m_pos.x)) + ((en_pos.y - m_pos.y) * (en_pos.y - m_pos.y)) + ((en_pos.z - m_pos.z) * (en_pos.z - m_pos.z))));
    return res;
}
void aim(vec3 pos) {// function for aiming at a position
    *reinterpret_cast<float*>(Player + MouseX) = pos.x;
    *reinterpret_cast<float*>(Player + MouseY) = pos.y;
}
DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID lpArgs) {
    while (true) {
        int onlinePlayers = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(OnlinePlayers);
        int myTeam = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(Player + Team);
        vec3 MyPos;

        MyPos.x = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(Player + HeadX);
        MyPos.y = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(Player + HeadX);
        MyPos.z = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(Player + HeadX);
        if (onlinePlayers > 1) {
            for (DWORD x = 0x4; x <= (0x4 * (onlinePlayers - 1)); x += 0x4) {
                DWORD EnemyBase = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(EntityList + x);
                DWORD EnemyTeam = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(EnemyBase + Team);
                vec3 EnemyPos;

                EnemyPos.x = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(EnemyBase + HeadX);
                EnemyPos.y = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(EnemyBase + HeadY);
                EnemyPos.z = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(EnemyBase + HeadZ);

                float Distance = GetDistance3D(MyPos, EnemyPos);
                if (EnemyTeam == myTeam) {
                    MessageBoxA(0, "Enemy is on your team", "Enemy Detected", 0);
                }
                else {
                    MessageBoxA(0, "Enemy is not on your team", "Enemy Detected", 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(0, 0, MainThread, 0, 0, 0);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: This just means that a pointer you read is actually not a pointer. You read something wrong. A few unrelated tips: If you want to read structured data in memory, it would be more practical to actually define the corresponding `struct` in your code and use that instead. Also, I'd recommend using `intptr_t` for storing pointers, instead of a fixed `DWORD`.

Comment: Plus. all of those `reinterpret_cast`'s -- if what is sitting at those locations are not `float`, `int`, etc.  then the behavior of the code is undefined.  If you're asking someone to debug this code, then I'm sorry to say that you're probably the only one that will be able to debug it, given what the code is doing (and assuming).